# Remember Gridview state with checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, gridview, checkbox

I have a webform with a gridview. On that Gridview there are checkboxes. All the items from my gridview is from my database.

What I want to know is how can I make the gridview remember my choices when I navigate back again to that page.

Can you show me a generic way to this.?

Thanks!

Comment: You can manage it using sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this :

**ASPX :**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat="server" OnRowCommand="grdView_OnRowCommand">
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server"
CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="chkbocCheck"
  AutoPostBack="true"   />
           </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

**CS :**

```
protected void grdView_OnRowCommand (object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
       string part = button.CommandArgument;   
           int rowIndex = Int32.Parse(part);
          CheckBox chk= null;
          if (rowIndex != -1)
            {
               chk= (CheckBox   )gvAlertSummary.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("chkBox");
                // Write your logic here
 } 
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

**Session and cookies**
Use `Session["value"]` and put there the value what checkbox is activate.
Then `onload()` check if the `Session["value"]` is something and put the checkboxSomething parameter selected true. Don't have computer now, so I can't show you the code.
Hopefully you got it.
About more of sessions you find here:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28VS.100%29.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said all the items in gridview are from database then you can save your choices to database first. So when you com back t your page it will fill-up from db and you get your filled data (choices) again.

Another way is you can store those values either in a `Session` variable or in `Cookie` at the `rowcommand` of gridview and get them when get back to the page.